# Checking if a URL exists or not

Tags: java, url

I need to check whether a URL exists or not. I want to write a servlet for this i.e. to check whether a URL exists or not. If the URL entered does not exist, then it should return some message.

Comment: A URL cannot in general be said to not exist.

Answer (score 26):

Better solution for HTTP :

```
public static boolean exists(String URLName){
    try {
      HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
      // note : you may also need
      //        HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
      HttpURLConnection con =
         (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
      con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
      return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return false;
    }
  }
```

If you are looking for any other URL try this code

```
  public static boolean exists(String URLName){
      boolean result = false;
      try {
          url = new URL("ftp://ftp1.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/");
          //url = new URL("ftp://ftp1.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD123/");//this will fail

          input = url.openStream();

           System.out.println("SUCCESS");
           result = true;

            } catch (Exception ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
         return result;
  }
```

**Source** :http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0059.html

Comment: `http` is not the only protocol/scheme in an URL.

Comment: @Michael Konietzka Update probably answers your comment

Comment: I need to use Httpclient and its methods to check for url existence
can u please tell how to use httpClient service.I tried to write this service in one servelt but it is giving exception.

Comment: @ha22109  if you are only concern with HTTP then first code should work for you perfectly

Comment: what about `mailto:example@example.com`?

Comment: @Michael Konietzka by URL I mean address to some resource above can't be checked for validity ,in such cases you need to contact @example.com

Comment: but is is a valid URL which exists. ;-)

Comment: @Michael Konietzka OP is just concern about HTTP  protocol :) it is not given in requirement list ;)

Comment: I cannot see this in the requirements. ;-) OP is talking from URLs in general. ;-). Additionally the interpretation of `exist` is not clear. What does existence of a URL mean? From my point of view, the URL already exists when I write it down resp create it. Maybe the OP just wanted to know if an HTTP-Resource represented by a HTTP-URL would be accessible for him, but that was not what the OP asked. ;-)

Comment: @Michael Konietzka from the comment of OP in the same thread it is clear that he wants to ask about HTTP protocol only, he has asked it globally actually

Comment: @org.life.java: My last comment contained some ironic note based on my sunday evening mood, which was lost when transporting via HTTP. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could try HTTP's `HEAD` method to see if the server returns a status code of `200` on a particular URL and act accordingly.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol and scroll down to the **Request Methods**.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a connection, get the input stream back, and check for null.

Answer (score -3):

I used this bash script for check urls, but need put all files in a file "urls.csv"

```
#!/bin/bash

###############################################
# mailto: ggerman@gmail.com
# checkurls
# https://github.com/ggerman/checkurls/
# require curl
###############################################

url() {
  cat urls.csv | 
  replace  | 
  show
}

replace() {
  tr ',' ' '
}

show() {
  awk '{print $1}'
}

url | \
while read CMD; do
  echo $CMD
  curl -Is $CMD | head -n 1
done
```

Comment: I've downvoted, since the question is tagged with Java