# Android: Download JPG if statement

Tags: android, webserver, jpeg

I have an Android app that downloads a JPG from a server every so often, and I need to be able to display a "Down for Maintenance" image whenever a certain file is present on the internet. 
Example:
Phone checks for "yes.maint" or some other file on a web server - if present, it shows maintenance image instead of other image. If not present, load other image as normal.

Is this possible in Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file "yes.maint" or some of other file is accessible via HTTP, you could use [HTTPClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) and call execute to get the [HTTPResponse](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html). You then call getStatusLine() to check and get the status code for that from [StatusLine getStatusCode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html#getStatusCode%28%29). If it is not found, hopefully you get 404 that you could use to check which image you have to load

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is the best way to implement some thing like this 
This  sounds more like a quick and dirty solution but it is possible

anyway here is an example class for http download it should do the trick

```
http download java get
//------------------------------------------------------------//
//  JavaGetUrl.java:                                          //
//------------------------------------------------------------//
//  A Java program that demonstrates a procedure that can be  //
//  used to download the contents of a specified URL.         //
//------------------------------------------------------------//
//  Code created by Developer's Daily                         //
//  http://www.DevDaily.com                                   //
//------------------------------------------------------------//

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class JavaGetUrl {

   public static void main (String[] args) {

      //-----------------------------------------------------//
      //  Step 1:  Start creating a few objects we'll need.
      //-----------------------------------------------------//

      URL u;
      InputStream is = null;
      DataInputStream dis;
      String s;

      try {

         //------------------------------------------------------------//
         // Step 2:  Create the URL.                                   //
         //------------------------------------------------------------//
         // Note: Put your real URL here, or better yet, read it as a  //
         // command-line arg, or read it from a file.                  //
         //------------------------------------------------------------//

         u = new URL("http://200.210.220.1:8080/index.html");

         //----------------------------------------------//
         // Step 3:  Open an input stream from the url.  //
         //----------------------------------------------//

         is = u.openStream();         // throws an IOException

         //-------------------------------------------------------------//
         // Step 4:                                                     //
         //-------------------------------------------------------------//
         // Convert the InputStream to a buffered DataInputStream.      //
         // Buffering the stream makes the reading faster; the          //
         // readLine() method of the DataInputStream makes the reading  //
         // easier.                                                     //
         //-------------------------------------------------------------//

         dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

         //------------------------------------------------------------//
         // Step 5:                                                    //
         //------------------------------------------------------------//
         // Now just read each record of the input stream, and print   //
         // it out.  Note that it's assumed that this problem is run   //
         // from a command-line, not from an application or applet.    //
         //------------------------------------------------------------//

         while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
         }

      } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {

         System.out.println("Ouch - a MalformedURLException happened.");
         mue.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(1);

      } catch (IOException ioe) {

         System.out.println("Oops- an IOException happened.");
         ioe.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(1);

      } finally {

         //---------------------------------//
         // Step 6:  Close the InputStream  //
         //---------------------------------//

         try {
            is.close();
         } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // just going to ignore this one
         }

      } // end of 'finally' clause

   }  // end of main

} // end of class definition
```

Comment: or take a look at this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596447/java-check-if-file-exists-on-remote-server-using-its-url