# Android - Check if PDF-file exists

Tags: java, android, eclipse, pdf, exists

I want to check if a pdf-file (this one: http://www.augustinianum.eu/roosterwijzigingen/14062012.pdf)
I tried this:

```
File fileTest = new File("http://www.augustinianum.eu/roosterwijzigingen/14062012.pdf");
 if(fileTest.exists()){
     //DO STUFF
 }
```

But it doesn't execute the if block. How is that possible? The PDF does exist.

It's probably an easy question, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thank You!

Comment: No, Application can not Force Close. If you properly Handle the Exception on Download File.

Comment: Thank you so much. Gonna give it a try tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the URL of file is for the server you can't access `File` like this,

For this **you have to first download this file on android device**, then using `File` class of Android you can check its existence.

**Example:**

Suppose you downloaded file on sdcard from this URL using `HttpPost` or `URLConnection`,

then

```
File fileTest = new File("/mnt/sdcard/14062012.pdf"); //Virtually path of your pdf file after download
 if(fileTest.exists()){
     //DO STUFF
 }
```

Now your `if` block will executed..

Comment: Hmm, isn't there another way to check wheter that pdf exists on the web or not?

Comment: Yes Look at this SO question [Java check if file exists on remote server using its url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596447/java-check-if-file-exists-on-remote-server-using-its-url)

Comment: And to download file from server http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device

Comment: But what I don't understand is this: developer.android.com says there's a constructor method which is `File(URI uri)`, but when I create a URI this way `URI uriTest = new URI("http://www.augustinianum.eu/roosterwijzigingen/14062012.pdf");` and make a file this way `File fileTest = new File(uriTest);` I'm getting a force close. Why is that?

Comment: Its for `Uri` not for `URL`. Actually, the constructor `File(Uri)` is for specified resource uri respect to other applications. Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File(java.net.URI)

Comment: And if I'd make my code download the file. Will the user see the download icon in the statusbar?

Comment: No, If you implement download code within your application user can not seen Download Icon on Statusbar.

Comment: And is it possible to delete that downloaded pdf-file in my code?

Comment: And one more question: Will the app force close when I command it to download a file which is not available? (BTW I really appreciate your help and patience, ty)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly access file like this using `File` class.

You may need to consider using `HTTPURLConnection` API for this purpose.