# How to check image exist in a particular location?

Tags: java, file

Is there any way to check image exist in a particular location except the following code?This code is taking too much time.

```
  static boolean isImage(String image_path){  
    InputStream input = null;
    try{

        URL url = new URL(image_path);
        input = url.openStream();
        return  true;

    }catch(Exception ex){
        return  false;
    }

  }
```

Comment: [Check if file exists on remote server using its URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596447/check-if-file-exists-on-remote-server-using-its-url) and [How do I check if a file exists in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java)

Comment: I don't have permission and exist() method returns true if file exist and have permission @ Jonjongot?

Comment: if you don't  have permission on it, it will throw `SecurityException`. means  if you get this exception, the file is exist.

Comment: @ Jonjongot  I am getting false even if file exists not SecurityException.

Comment: not sure if you get what i'm saying or I don't understand you. Try add one more catch block just before your catch block above `catch(SecurityException se){
        return  true;
    }`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check if the file exists:

```
static boolean isImage(String image_path){  
    try{
        File f = new File(image_path);
        return  f.exists();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        return  false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have permission and exist() method returns true if file exist and have permission @ StephaneM?