# check if file exist on remote server using Java code

Tags: java, file, io

I wanted to write sample code which will connect to remote server and check if the given file exist on that server.
I have IP address, username, password and port.
Is there any way I can check if the file exist on remote server?
I know this can be done using third party library.
But I am looking using java APi's
Could you please help me?

Comment: Is the server running done sort of protocol?

Answer (score -1):

Check this question in Stack Overflow: [Check if file exists on remote server using its URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596447/check-if-file-exists-on-remote-server-using-its-url)

It has an answer to your question:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public static boolean exists(String URLName) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        // note : you may also need
        //        HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
        HttpURLConnection con =
               (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

        return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }
}
```

> If the connection to a URL (made with HttpURLConnection) returns with
>   HTTP status code 200 then the file exists.