# Java file exists at URL

Tags: java, file, url, exists

Does anybody know a reliable method for seeing if a file exists at a URL, in Java?

Trying to see if the file exists before it is downloaded.

(HTTP, btw.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [checking a url exist or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177864/checking-a-url-exist-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

```
URL url = new URL ( some_url );
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

connection.connect();

// Cast to a HttpURLConnection
if ( connection instanceof HttpURLConnection)
{
   HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;

   int code = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

   // do something with code .....
}
else
{
   System.err.println ("error - not a http request!");
}
```

`Usually HTTP error codes of 2xx represent success and 3xx for moved/redirection`.

If you do get '3xx' errors, the response contains one or more header lines of the form `URI: <url> String CrLf`, use this new `url` and repeat above process.

Comment: don't forget to select the answer that helped you the most, by putting a tick mark sign !

Answer (score 1):

File exists URI with JAVA you can use :

**Files.exists(Paths.get(URI))**

But that solution is not working with HTTP protocol (URL)

instead, you can use the snippet below to verify file existence for **http://** or **file://**

```
    try {
    InputStream openConnection = URI.create("https://your.domain.p1/path/1233/file.doc").toURL().openStream();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(" invalid resource ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to do this generically. If you know that URL is a local url with a "file:" protocol, you can convert it into a regular File object and check its existence that way. If the protocol is "http:", etc. you cannot check for existence without trying to open a stream. Even then you need to interpret the response (in protocol-dependent fashion) in order to know if something is there. For HTTP, you will probably get 404 response if file isn't found, but it could be another response code. Depends on the service you are accessing.

Comment: Yea, I tried using HttpURLConnection and it gave me 302's every time.

Comment: 302 is a re-direct request. You have to follow the re-direct to see if the file exists. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: I know, if it let it follow redirects, it gave me 200's, even though one file I know doesn't exist.

Comment: Look at the content of 200 response for the non-existing files. Some web services that serve "files" will not give you a traditional 404 response as they expect to communicate with a human viewing content in a browser. For such "non-comforming" services, you will have to parse out the response html content to figure out if you got a failure. Nothing generic about that solution, but about the only thing you can do in some cases.