# how to determine if file with ftp url exists?

Tags: java, url, ftp, download

my main goal is to make an image of the first page PDF file. The file placed on the internet public directory. It's sometimes FTP and sometimes HTTP URL

```
private void downloadTheFile(String path, String name) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    InputStream in;
    in = new URL(path).openStream();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(name + ".pdf");
    try {
        byte buf[] = new byte[4096];
        for (int n = in.read(buf); n > 0; n = in.read(buf)) {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

the problem is, that when i want to download a ftp file like:
ftp://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/pub/cmp/articles/bakstein/Bakstein-TR-2006-09.pdf
and it doesnt exists, it stops the whole procces

i should always ask if it really exists before i download the file somehow, but i only found some solution for http urls

could anyone help me please?

Comment: You can also take a look here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/ This can help you to solve many internet protocols problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a check too see if the URL can be reached first and in that case handle that case.

This question has some snippets that could be useful for you to check the URL:
[Checking if a URL exists or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177864/checking-a-url-exist-or-not)

Comment: Oh, I already visited this, but now it helped me to realise something that I didnt see. Thank you